# Excel VBA - Issues with Match and LookupDict

Tags: excel, vba

My code first loads data from one sheet into a dictionary. It then looks for the column header on another sheet. Then loop through all data in the column found referencing the dictionary to look up UUIDs and replacing them their corresponding data. The data being replaced looks like

`["8b02d220-ba28-4f57-a412-1ea3e4ec6f2b","0acea99b-73c5-47da-bc5b-1ea3ea10505b","51a85733-a668-4b35-992a-1eb0c27d258b","7bf6e02e-5c2d-4718-bd64-1ea3ed414cdb","53011b9e-b67f-43d9-a6b2-1eb0cac34e9b","0f5f0122-7435-4621-bfa9-1eb0ce52669b"]`.

Some cells are empty other have a dozen or so in them. It needs to grab each segment wrapped by quotes replace it with it corresponding data to look like this.

```
One, Two, Three, Four
```

My code runs through everything but on the If `LookUpDict.Exists(match)` it never find a match and does nothing. When I Debug.Print the match have `"0acea99b-73c5-47da-bc5b-1ea3ea10505b"` loaded. I tried doing Replace and removed the quotes `0acea99b-73c5-47da-bc5b-1ea3ea10505b` but it had no effect. I never get a error, in fact have no error catching even setup right now. Please Help

```
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Ws5 As Worksheet
Dim Ws6 As Worksheet

Dim staffData As Variant
Dim clientData As Variant
Dim categoryData As Variant
Dim queueData As Variant
Dim badgeData As Variant

Dim staffLastRow As Long
Dim clientLastRow As Long
Dim categoryLastRow As Long
Dim queueLastRow As Long
Dim badgeLastRow As Long

Dim ColumnUUID As Range
Dim jobLastRow As Long
Dim jobValue As String
Dim joblastCol As Long
Dim jobCell As Range
Dim jobcolrange As Variant
    
Dim cellValue As String
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

y = 1

Dim LookUpDict As Object

Dim startTime As Double
Dim stoptime As Double

Dim matches As Object
Dim UUIDList As Object
Set UUIDList = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")

startTime = Timer

Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("job")
Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("staff")
Set Ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("category")
Set Ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("client")
Set Ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("queues")
Set Ws6 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Badges")

With UUIDList
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = """(.*?)"""
End With

For i = 1 To UBound(badgeData)
    LookUpDict(badgeData(i, 1)) = badgeData(i, 7)
Next i

For i = 1 To joblastCol
    cellValue = jobcolrange(1, i)
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "badges", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).Resize(Ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).row)
        For Each jobCell In ColumnUUID.Cells
            Set matches = UUIDList.Execute(jobCell.value)
            x = matches.Count
                If x <= 1 Then
                Else
                    If x = 1 Then
                        For Each match In matches
                            If LookUpDict.Exists(match) Then
                                jobCell.value = LookUpDict(match)
                            End If
                        Next match
                    Else
                        For Each match In matches
                            If LookUpDict.Exists(match) Then
                                jobCell.value = jobCell.value & ", " & LookUpDict(match)
                            End If
                        Next match
                    End If
                    y = 1
                End If
        Next jobCell
    End If
Next i
```

This is only the meat and potato's portion of my code, it to large to load it all.

Comment: I don't get this: `If x <= 1 Then: Else: If x = 1 Then` Are you checking twice if is equal to 1?

Comment: No it's suppose to be `If x < 1 Then: Else: If x = 1 Then`. That explain another issue I was have with it not selecting the right option, I missed that one. But I wasn't to worried about it as the whole function does not work. Thank you I fixed it.

Comment: Add else block to `If LookUpDict.Exists(match) Then` with `debug.print match` to see which matches are not existing.

Comment: `(.*?)` Do you need to use a regex, wouldn't `split(string,",")` do ?

Comment: Try `.Pattern = "([A-Z0-9-]+)"`

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply had other thing come up and haven't been on. For CDP1802, I already tried Debug.Print and it does not find any match, all fail the LookUpDict(Match). As for the `split(string,",")` this doesn't work either, because of the [] & "" the (match) comes back with different formats depending on if it is the fisrt, middle or last UUID. i.e. `["***` or `"***"` or `***"]`. I tried this .Pattern Tim Williams but it had no effect, the (match) still comes back as `"***"` but it never find a match so never replaces the cell value.

Comment: FYI it might be worth taking a step back and figuring out how to split your code up into different methods - preferably ones which are parameterized so you can avoid a lot of repetition in your code.  I see a common pattern in your questions - [1] build a lookup dictionary from a range of data (3 variable parts: the range, the "key" column" and the "Value" column  [2] The "replace" operation, where the variable part is the range to replace in.  If you make one or two methods to do this, you can call them repeatedly with different ranges/columns.